# Firebase : Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/object.change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-tools, firebase-cli

Can anyone tell me how to fix the following storage trigger error:

```
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/object.change
```

Strange thing is some of the triggers deploy successfully. 
All of the triggers deployed successfully just a week ago and we haven't changed our environment or SDK.
We are using firebase-tools 3.14.0

The code for one of the failed triggers looks like this:

```
  opBudget_process_div : functions.storage.object()
  .onChange(event => {
    if(event.data.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
      console.log("Deletion event.");
      return;
    }
    var path_arr = event.data.name.split("/");
    if(path_arr.indexOf('ack-store-visit') == -1 || path_arr.indexOf('meta') == -1
        || path_arr.indexOf('kpi_op_budget') == -1){
      /**
      * NOTE: Currently all files uploaded to the bucket will trigger this function.
      * We perform this check to stop undesired files from being processed.
      * TODO: Maybe also check the file extension
      */
      return;
    }
    return require("./kpi_op_budget/process")
      .sync_op_budget_div(event.data, "operational_budget");
}),
```

The text version of the error we get in the terminal is:

> ```
> ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-people_process]: Successful update operation.
> ```
>
> ⚠  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-opBudget_process]: Deployment error.
>   Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/object.change
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-storeAnalysis_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-cellOps_process]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-sales_process]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-stockLoss_process]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-people_process_div]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-stockLoss_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-storeAnalysis_process]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-officers_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-sales_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-ramDb_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-people_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-opBudget_process_div]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-internalAudit_import]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-stockLoss_process_div]: Successful update operation. 
>   ✔  functions[forms_ack_store_visit-meta-ramDb_process_div]: Successful update operation.

Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

[image]

Comment: Please include your error as texts instead of an image.

Comment: @AndréKool the error is in the title, the grey area and the image.
its Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/object.change

Comment: You should copy the text of code and error messages directly into your question so they're easier to read and search.